# Php / mysqli Selling system

Tags: php, mysqli

So, i'm doing a project in php/mysqli and i'm trying to do a selling  system where i have 3 table involve in the sell page. One is where i want to pass the product , the other one is where i want to pass the seller id.
For the product i need to pass the fk (product_id ) so i can get the price and to my jquery process it  doing the math. At the moment the system is working but i dont know how to go with this so i can get my database products and sellers selected instead of the options on the form. I have never done a sell system so i'm a bit loss at this part.

This is my code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){

           var codigoDeBarras = $('input[name="codigoDeBarras"]');
           var nif = $('input[name="NIF"]');
           var valorUnidade = $('input[name="valorUnidade"]');
           var valorTotal = $('input[name="valorTotal"]');
           var quantidade = $('input[name="Quantidade"]');

           $('select#produtos').change(function(){
              if( !$(this).find('option:selected').val() == '' ){
                  var price = parseInt($(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-price'));
                  var code = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-code');
                  $('#price').html(price);
                  $('#total_price').html(price * parseInt(quantidade.val()));
                  codigoDeBarras.val(code);
                  valorUnidade.val(price);
                  valorTotal.val(price * parseInt(quantidade.val()));
              }
           });
           quantidade.bind('click keyup', function(){
              if( !$('select#produtos').find('option:selected').val() == '' ){
                  var price =  $('select#produtos').find('option:selected').attr('data-price');
                  $('#total_price').html(price * parseInt($(this).val()));
                  valorTotal.val(price * parseInt(quantidade.val()));
              }
           });
           $('select#fornecedor').change(function(){
              if( !$(this).find('option:selected').val() == '' ){
                nif.val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-nif'));
              }
           });
        });
    </script>

<?PHP
session_start();
    $host="xxxx"; // Host name 
    $username="xxxx"; // Mysql username 
    $password="xxxx"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="xxx"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="utilizador";


    // Connect to server and select databse.
    $link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysqli_select_db($link , $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

    // CHECK LOG IN

    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
        echo "";

} else {
    header('Location: ../index.php');
}
    // END OF LOG IN CHECK
$link->close();

?>

<html lang="en"> 

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesVenda.css"></link>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesF.php"></link>

</head>

<body>

<div id="background"> </div>
<div id="topBar">
    <div class="topBox">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> 
    </div>
        <div id="rightSideBox">
            <h2>WineControl</h2>
        </div>

        <a href="homepage.php"><h2>Homepage</h2></a>
    </div>

    <div id="sideBar">
        <div id="add">

        </div>
</div>

<div id="headerWrap">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="moveDown">

        </div>

        <div class="container">

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="codigoDeBarras">
        <input type="hidden" name="NIF">
        <input type="hidden" name="valorUnidade">
        <input type="hidden" name="valorTotal">
        <p>
            <label>Data</label>
            <input type="date" name="DataDeEncomenda">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Escolher Produto</label>
            <select id="produtos">
                <option value="">Escolher Produto</option>
                <option data-price="5.00" data-code="109000">Produto 1</option>  

                <option data-price="10.00" data-code="109001">Produto 2</option>
                <option data-price="15.00" data-code="109002">Produto 3</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Escolher Fornecedor</label>
            <select id="fornecedor">
                <option value="">Escolher Fornecedor</option>
                <option data-nif="900001" data-code="109000">Fornecedor 1</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Quantidade</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" name="Quantidade" value="1">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Preco(Unidade)</label>
            <span id="price">0.00</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Valor Total</label>
            <span id="total_price">0.00</span>
        </p>
    </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know this is a big question but if you could give me a idea how to go with this it would be very helpful.

EDIT : So, now i can get the data from the jquery into and array but still dont know how to apply the selected option into my database ... This is my code :

```
    <?php


$mysqli = new mysqli("xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx", xxxx);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}


   if( $_POST != '' && $_POST != NULL ){

                $query = "SELECT * FROM produto";
                $from = 0;
                $to = 30;
                $query .= " LIMIT ".$from.",".$to;

            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . $mysqli->error);
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                $produtos[] = array(
                    'Preco' => $row['Preco'],
                    'Nome' => $row['nome']

                 );
            }
            echo json_encode($produtos);

                $query2 = "SELECT * FROM fornecedor";
                $from = 0;
                $to = 30;
                $query .= " LIMIT ".$from.",".$to;

            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die("SQL Error 1: " . $mysqli->error);
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                $fornecedor[] = array(
                    'NIF' => $row['NIF'],
                    'Nome' => $row['Nome']

                 );
            }
            echo json_encode($fornecedor);

            print_r($fornecedor);


            $encomenda_data = $_POST['DataDeEncomenda'];
            $encomenda_qty = $_POST['Quantidade'];
            $encomenda_nif = $fornecedor[0]; // Forget this line and the other bellow ( testing purpose)
            $encomenda_codigo = $_POST['Produto'];
            $encomenda_preco = $produtos[0];
            $encomenda_total = $_POST['valor'];


            $sql3 = "INSERT INTO encomendain ( DataDeEncomenda, Quantidade, NIF, codigoDeBarras, Preço, ValorTotal) VALUES ( '$encomenda_data' , '$encomenda_qty' , '$encomenda_nif' , '$encomenda_codigo' , '$encomenda_preco', '$encomenda_total') ";


            $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql3) or die("Could not insert".mysqli_error($link));
            header('Location: paginaEncomendaIn.php');

        }


    ?>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure on you question. Is it basically how to connect a database. If so there are plenty of examples on the internet for example see http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/phpintegration/bind-jquery-grid-to-mysql-database-using-php.htm

Comment: What i want is to add the options in the form the corresponding fields in my database, by selecting the product the form must know the price of him so it can know the final value . I can do that inserting values ex.: data-price="10.00" but what i want is the price of the product picked on the top

Answer (score -1):

To connect to your database use (Copied from http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database", 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
?>
```

To read from a table and store in a jquery array mainly copied from http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/phpintegration/bind-jquery-grid-to-mysql-database-using-php.htm adapted to used mysqli

```
// get data and store in a json array
$query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
$from = 0;
$to = 30;
$query .= " LIMIT ".$from.",".$to;

$result = mysqli_query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . $mysqli->error);
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $customers[] = array(
        'CompanyName' => $row['CompanyName'],
        'ContactName' => $row['ContactName'],
        'ContactTitle' => $row['ContactTitle'],
        'Address' => $row['Address'],
        'City' => $row['City']
     );
}
echo json_encode($customers);
```

You will need modify this to read from your database and populate fields in your html form.

Comment: I have done it and i'm now able to get the data into the arrays , but how do i insert the data selected in my database ? I'll edit up, so you can see better what i have done .

Comment: Use the SQL INSERT statement.